# Search for header and specific letters in lines and print both python

Tags: python

Search for "Cluster" and specific letters in lines **st104, pK** in (st104H_20170,pKH911_25081).

If the lines below the header have both the initials **st104,pK** print header and the lines.

**input.txt**
Cluster 1
0 673aa -st104P_06575
1 673aa -st104H_22488
3 673aa -pKH911_09284
4 673aa -pKP911_09288
Cluster 2
0 690aa -st104H_20170
1 690aa -KH911_25081
2 687aa -NE95031.1
3 685aa -TIG_004920
Cluster 3
0 685aa -st104H_27649
1 690aa -st104P_11877
2 685aa -pKP911_15300
Cluster 4
0 685aa -st104H_27649
1 690aa -st104P_11877

**output**
Cluster 1
0 673aa -st104P_06575
1 673aa -st104H_22488
3 673aa -pKH911_09284
4 673aa -pKP911_09288
Cluster 3
0 685aa -st104H_27649
1 690aa -st104P_11877
2 685aa -pKP911_15300

**Tried:**

```
with open("input.txt") as fh:
    result = ""
    cluster_content = ""
    for line in fh:
    if line.startswith("Cluster"):
        if all(initial in cluster_content for initial in ('st104', 'pK')):
           result += cluster_content
        cluster_content = ""
    cluster_content += line
```

Comment: But none of the output contains "NE" or "TIG"?

Comment: Also, your indentation is off after `for line in fh:`

Comment: Are you just trying to filter out the clusters that have both `st` and `pK` in them?

Comment: Johnny, yes just the st104,pK. I have a big file. I have updated the code

Andrew: I want the clusters with st and pK, (even if the are repeated)

Comment: Then why do you have "NE" and "TIG" in `...for initial in ('st104', 'pK', 'NE', 'TIG')):` ?

Answer (score 0):

This would filter the st104 and pK clusters

```
# true if filter_str is only one used
def check_alone(cluster_content, filter_str, cluster_split):
    return cluster_content.count(filter_str) == len(cluster_split) - 1

def cluster_filter(cluster_content):
    filters_labels = ['st104', 'pK']
    cluster_split = cluster_content.split('\n')
    if cluster_split[-1] == '': # to remove the last empty string in list
        cluster_split = cluster_split[:-1]

    if check_alone(cluster_content, 'st104', cluster_split) or check_alone(cluster_content, 'pK', cluster_split):
        return 

    # checking if each of the strings contain any of the filter_labels and making sure that all of the strings in the cluster contain an item from the filter
    if all(any(label in item for label in filters_labels) for item in cluster_split[1:]):
        print(cluster_content)


with open("input.txt") as fh:
    result = ""
    cluster_content = ""
    for line in fh:
        if line.startswith("Cluster"):
            cluster_filter(cluster_content)
            cluster_content = line
        else:
            cluster_content += line
    cluster_filter(cluster_content)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
Cluster 1
0 673aa -st104P_06575
1 673aa -st104H_22488
3 673aa -pKH911_09284
4 673aa -pKP911_09288

Cluster 3
0 685aa -st104H_27649
1 690aa -st104P_11877
2 685aa -pKP911_15300
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thank you so much.  Line 2: (if 'st104' in cluster_content and 'pK' in cluster_content:) if i have 8 names (st, pK, tS, sX, pT,gC,hT,gL) in cluster_content. how do i parse it? if 'st104' in cluster_content and 'pK' in cluster_content and 'tS' in cluster_content and 'sX' in cluster_content: etc. does give me output. 

All the names must be present in the cluster.

Comment: I am guessing what you are saying is how to create a filter where all of the names in a cluster a present. So for example with your list of 8 names (previously) you want to match clusters that only contain those names and if there is a line that does not match those names, then you won't print out that cluster. Can you give a more concrete example of what you mean (unsure if I am interpreting you correctly)?

Comment: Yes, the cluster should contain all the names. In the above question, Cluster1 and 3 has both sT and pK so should be printed. Cluster 4 has only sT (no pK) so should not be printed. For the code (if 'st104' in cluster_content and 'pK' in cluster_content:) If i have more than two names it would be lengthy to repeat - (if 'st104' in cluster_content and 'pK' in cluster_content and 'tS' in cluster_content and 'sX' in cluster_content:) how can this be shortened?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I am getting cluster 4 also. It has only st104 but no pK. Thanks

Comment: so are there filters that need to be together? or are there filters that can not be alone?

Comment: The filters_labels ( 'st104' and 'pK') should be under the header(Cluster) and together, cannot be alone, if alone no need to print.

Comment: I am still getting Cluster 4: (0 685aa -st104H_27649, 1 690aa -st104P_11877)

Comment: @pathogen1 updated. accidentally left the and statment in when I meant or